# Why does the font-size change for container bigger than 50%?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, font-size

This is a little test page. On the desktop it looks normal to me.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <style type="text/css">
    div {
      background: green;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:10%">10%</div>
  <div style="width:20%">20%</div>
  <div style="width:30%">30%</div>
  <div style="width:40%">40%</div>
  <div style="width:50%">50%</div>
  <div style="width:60%">60%</div>
  <div style="width:70%">70%</div>
  <div style="width:80%">80%</div>
  <div style="width:90%">90%</div>
  <div style="width:100%">100%</div>
</body>

</html>
```

But on my iPhone it has a strange behavior. In portrait mode everything is ok. **But in landscape mode the browser calculates different font sizes although they are all set to 15px.** Is there something I don't understand about font-size? I need them to look all the same.

[image: View from Safari on iPhone]

Same thing happens on firefox, edge and chrome

Comment: if thats you're real  code, then Safari is being buggy here. :( give it a try with a rem unit instead px to check it out.

Comment: I tried it out in the simulator (iPhone 12 Pro Max with iOS 14.4) and can't reproduce what you describe. Are you sure this is your full code?

Comment: this code is for demonstrating my problem. The simulator and an android device do not show this behavior. The picture is a screen grab of an iPhone. Same thing happens on firefox on my iPhone. Forgot to mention, that it only happens in landscape mode

Comment: @ThomasTrautwein Thanks for specifying, having the phone in landscape mode does seem to be the crux of the issue here. I can replicate that in both the simulator as well as on a real device. I would even recommend bolding that part of the sentence since the bug is not reproducible otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked on the apple.com web page to see if they have the same issue. And they don't.

They use

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

and then the font size is everywhere the same.

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me (actually, I use "-webkit-text-size-adjust: none") . Without this declaration, the website changes font sizes in an apparently non-deterministic way when changing between portrait and landscape. @thomas, you might improve this answer by adding some words about what text-size-adjust is for. I was at first ignoring your answer because it seemed unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an attempt to provide more debugging details to others looking into the issue.

---

I reproduced the bug in [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n32s05bp/show) to easily inspect it in the official Simulator. To inspect the page as Simulator renders it, open the page in Simulator, then open Safari on the host system and go to Settings → Advanced → enable Show Develop Menu. Following this, you can use Develop → Simulator → Show to inspect the page.

Following the above, the bug is reproducable when the phone is in landscape mode.
Inspecting the page, the styles on the element are shown as they should be. However, looking at the **computed** styles, we can see that a new font-size value of 21px has appeared with no inheritance.
Following the style's reference simply takes us to the 15px font-size definition.

[image: Screenshot of Safari's inspector]

Setting `!important` or other alternative configurations seem to have no effect on this value.

Outside of a better explanation, I would recommend [reporting this as a bug in Safari](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html).

Comment: This also happens on installed chrome, edge and firefox. Are they running the same rendering engine?

Comment: @ThomasTrautwein All browsers on iOS [use Safari as the rendering engine under the hood](https://www.baekdal.com/thoughts/apple-is-limiting-the-new-google-chrome-for-ios), Apple doesn't allow alternative browsers in their full form as a policy.

Comment: In the marked part of the picture, the "computed" font size of 21px obviously is different from the specified 15 px. This is not a bug but, according to the highest ranking answer, it is due to some Apple magic by which they try to adjust desktop pages to small screens.  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none should help.

Answer (score 0):

To learn more and possibly find some clues, put an ID on the div and adjust your CSS accordingly. See if the result changes. This *should* not be needed, but playing around and trying things usually reveals some clue.
Also, what happens if you move font-size:15px; to the div element (next to the width property) ? If these alternatives work, you can see them as a way to circumvent the fault.